# Formatting HTML with Nunjucks extension installed

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting, ide, nunjucks

I have some Angular component HTML `some.component.html` that I'm trying to format.  When I hit `ctrl-shift`p`, and select`Format Document` I get the message:

> There is no document formatter for 'nunjucks'-files installed.

So it seems VSCode thinks that the `.html` file is a nunjucks file.

Is there a way to make it think that it's a html file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch back to HTML by clicking on the word "Nunjucks" in VS Code's status bar. This "Language Indicator" is near the bottom-right of VS Code's window.  Clicking it will display a "Select Language Mode" drop-down-list where you can select "HTML".

After that, things that normally work for HTML files (like Format Document) will work again; however, things like the special syntax highlighting applied to Nunjuck files will not, but you can switch back and forth as needed.

Here's VS Code's documentation for [Changing the language for the selected file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file).

Comment: My sincere thanks for this. Right in front of my face the whole time!

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly adding a "file.associations" in settings.json seems to solve the need to switch back-and-forth.

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html",
}
```